# Are those proofs of $(-a)b = - (ab)$ and $(-a)(-b) = ab$ right?

Tags: proof-verification

I'm studying by Apostol and I need to proof both statements:

(1): $(-a)b = -(ab)$

(2): $(-a)(-b) = ab$

**My try at (1)**:

We can rewrite $(-a)$ as $(0 -a)$ by Th 1.2(already been proved), so we can rewrite (1) as $(0 - a)b$. By Commutative Laws, we have $(0 - a)b = b(0 - a)$ and by Th 1.5(which state that $a(b - c) = ab - ac$, and have already been proven) we have $b(0 - a) = b0 - ba$, so we do have $0 - ba$ which is $-ba$ or $-(ba)$. By Commutative Laws, we can rewrite $ba as ab$, so we have our desired value of $-(ab)$.

**My try at (2)**:

We can rewrite $(-a)$ as $(0 - a)$ by Th 1.2(already been proved). So we now have $(0 - a)(-b)$, which can be, by Th 1.5, rewritten as $0(-b) - a(-b)$, which is equal to $0 - a(-b)$ which is simple -a(-b). We can rewrite it as  $-(-b)a$ by Commutative Laws. But by (1) we have that $(-b)a = -(ba)$, so we end with $-(-(ba))$. And again by Commutative Laws we can rewrite $ba$ as $ab$ so we now have $-(-(ab))$. But we have also proved that $-(-a) = a$(Th 1.4) so we have $-(-(ab)) = (ab)$. Hence we got our desired expression.

Comment: Small typo I think you meant $0(-b) - a(-b)$ in the second paragraph.  I'm not seeing any immediate problem.  The most likely error is probably to mix up unary $-$ and binary $-$ but you seemed to have avoided that, good job.

Comment: Thanks for the correction

Comment: "so we do have 0−ba "  Have you proven that $b*0 = 0$?  That's probably *not* a given axiom.

Comment: "by Th 1.2(already been proved),"  If you quote a Theorem to us who do not know what book you are using, you need to tell use what Th. 1.2 says.  We can't tell you if your proof is good if we don't know what axioms, theorems (or even what book!) you are using.

Comment: @fleablood I will add those axioms, sorry for the mistake. As by "Have you proven that b∗0=0? That's probably not a given axiom", yes, I've already proven it